# Is there a difference between /etc/profile and a bash init file?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to extend my bash history size from 1000 commands to 10000 commands.

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.macromates.com/2008/working-with-history-in-bash/) to extend my bash history from 1000 commands to 10000. In the first paragraph, it says to append the following three lines to my 'bash init.'

```
export HISTCONTROL=erasedups
export HISTSIZE=10000
shopt -s histappend
```

Google lead me to the [bash beginner guide](http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_03_01.html) and I can't read it, since Bash isn't my first language. I think the following excerpt answers my question, but I'm not sure.

> When invoked interactively with the --login option or when invoked as sh, Bash reads the /etc/profile instructions. These usually set the shell variables PATH, USER, MAIL, HOSTNAME and HISTSIZE.

Questions I have:

1. Am I reading this right when I assume that /etc/profile is the same as a bash initialize?
2. How can I test if this worked?  /etc/profile currently looks like this:

   ```
   export HISTSIZE=10000 
   shopt -s histappend

   # System-wide .profile for sh(1)


   if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
      eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
   fi

   if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
      [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
   fi
   ```

Update: putting those commands in the bashrc didn't seem to do anything, but following [this add timestamps to bash history](http://larsmichelsen.com/open-source/bash-timestamp-in-bash-history/) tutorial, I put the commands in /etc/bashrc . My history now has timestamps.  Is it safe to assume that .bash_history now saves 100000 commands as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash may read several different files. Since these are `bash` specific options that don't work for `sh`, you should put them in `~/.bashrc` and make sure you have a line `source ~/.bashrc` in `~/.bash_profile`.

You can test it by opening a new terminal and running `echo $HISTCONTROL` and `shopt histappend` to see whether they have the expected values ("erasedups" and "on").

Comment: Thank you! is source ~/.bashrc the same as <code> if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc fi </code>? That is what I have.

Comment: It's the same concept but with system files instead of user files. You can add comments by prefixing with `#`, like in the code you posted.